# Saving ObjectId as reference dose not work in NodeJs MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am going to store a category id to an item.

I do the below .save() function to add a new row.

```
const myNewItem = {
    categoryId = ObjectId("5fc0a6e58dc3892120595384"),
    title = "Apple"
}
var myNewItemSave = await new Item(myNewItem).save();
```

However, when I check my database record

```
_id: ObjectId("..."),
categoryId: "5fc0a6e58dc3892120595384",
title: "Apple"
```

The categoryId is not saved as ObjectId.

I want to save it as ObjectId is because I am going to query some lookup aggregation like this:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/50y2zWj-bQ6

so I have to make localField and foreignField are the same type as ObjectId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen becuse your schema don't allow category id as mongoose objectId it is string

```
const schema = new Mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String },
    categoryId: { type: Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'categories' }
  },
  { timestamps: true, versionKey: false }
)
export default Mongoose.model('Items', schema)
```

Import Item model and save will convert string into mongoose objectId

```
const myNewItem = {
  categoryId: "5fc0a6e58dc3892120595384",
  title: "Apple"
}
const myNewItemSave = await Item.create(myNewItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ashok defines a type in the model, if you dont want to modify the model you can "convert" the id with `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`, eg:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const myNewItem = {
    categoryId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5fc0a6e58dc3892120595384"),
    title = "Apple"
}
```